# How to add Hindi/Devnagari Characters in Oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle, unicode, oracle10g

I am unable to insert Hindi characters in Oracle 10g database. Whatever I try to insert appears as `??????` in database.

I converted datatype to NVarchar and tried to insert using following command

```
Insert into MyTable (MyColumn) values (N'MyUnicodeString');
```

Still appears as `?????`

Tried to do same by passing parameters still not working.

Any help?

Comment: try after setting lanaguge to  NLS_LANG = HINDI_INDIA.JA16EUC

Comment: What is the value of 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET' when you run
    select * from v$nls_parameters?